# How to require a shared object file (nuklear.so) from a subdirectory in Love2D?

Tags: lua, love2d

For a small game, I'm trying out the [love-nuklear](https://github.com/keharriso/love-nuklear) library to create UIs. I've successfully built the .so by following the exact instructions provided by the author, see [this section](https://github.com/keharriso/love-nuklear#compiling-with-cmake-on-linux).

When `nuklear.so` is placed in the same directory as my `main.lua` file, `nuklear = require('nuklear.so')` imports the library correctly, and is accessible when I run `$ love .`.

However for better organization, I've decided to move `nuklear.so` into a subdirectoy `lib/`, where other lua modules are also imported. But now in `main.lua`, when using `nuklear = require('lib.nuklear')`, then running  `$ love .` in the project root directory, the following error is produced:

```
Error: error loading module 'lib.nuklear' from file './lib/nuklear.so':
        ./lib/nuklear.so: undefined symbol: luaopen_lib_nuklear
stack traceback:
        [string "boot.lua"]:637: in function <[string "boot.lua"]:633>
        [C]: at 0x7ff27837fc00
        [C]: in function 'require'
        main.lua:4: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        [string "boot.lua"]:475: in function <[string "boot.lua"]:311>
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'
        [string "boot.lua"]:645: in function <[string "boot.lua"]:639>
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

How should I correctly relocate my shared object from the project root directory to its `lib/` subdirectory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default when loading a C library, Lua looks for a function in the library named `luaopen_x`, where `x` is the module name with `.` replaced with `_` (and with some other transformations), and runs it. (See the [documentation for `package.searchers`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.searchers).) In this case the module name `lib.nuklear` results in the function name `luaopen_lib_nuklear`. But the function is actually named `luaopen_nuklear`, so Lua doesn't find it and can't load the library.

To fix this, you can add `./lib/?.so` to `package.cpath` before loading the library with `require "nuklear"`: `package.cpath = package.cpath .. ";./lib/?.so"`. Then Lua will look for `luaopen_nuklear` in `./lib/nuklear.so`. This will allow you to load other `.so` libraries in that directory.

Getting the source code of `nuklear.so` and renaming `luaopen_nuklear` to `luaopen_lib_nuklear` and recompiling would also work, but would be kind of silly and wouldn't solve the problem for other C libraries in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, and indeed that worked.